# Why do background images load when navigating by anchor link but not by routerLink?

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, parallax

I have a feeling the answer to this question is quite simple, but I cannot find an answer to it anywhere. I am build a very simple app with Vue.js (v2.6.11) that consists of just two pages, a home page and another page with a form. Now, on both of these pages, there are several parallax containers made with [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/parallax.html). If you're unfamiliar, a parallax container is basically just a div with an image as its background, and when the user scrolls, the background image moves at a different rate than the foreground of the site.

My problem is that when I navigate from the home page to the page with the form using a Vue.js link, `<router-link :to="{name: "FormPage"}>Form Page</router-link>`, the images in the parallax containers DO NOT load. However, if I refresh the page, the images load fine and everything is well. Similarly, If I replace the `<router-link>` with a simple `<a href="/FormPage">Form Page</a>` the images load fine, everything works as it should.

So my question is this: why don't my parallax container images load on the page navigated to with `<router-link></router-link>`, but then when I navigate to that same page with a `<a href=""></a>` the images do load? In other words, what is `<router-link></router-link>` doing that prevents my parallax container images from loading??

Any and all feedback would be appreciated. Otherwise, I hope you have a marvelous day, and thank you for you time in reading and or answering my question :)

--Update--
CODE:
This is the component on the homepage that contains the link in question:

```
<template>
  <div id="index-banner" class="parallax-container" style="height: 400px;">
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
      <div class="container">
        <br><br>
        <h1 class="header center white-text">{{ translations.title }}</h1>
        <div class="row center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 white-text light">{{ translations.subtitle }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row center">
          <!-- <router-link :to="{name: 'Generator', force: true }" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-1 center-align">{{ buttonText }}</router-link> -->
          <a href="/email-signature-generator" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-1 center-align">{{ translations.buttonText }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax"><img :src="img" alt="Unsplashed background img 1"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Banner1',
  props: {
    translations: String,
    img: String
  },
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

This is the 'view' that is navigated to, containing the parallax containers in question:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PageTitle
      :translations="$t('generatorPage.components.pageTitle')"
      img="/imgs/parallax5.jpeg"
    />
    <SigForm 
      :translations="$t('generatorPage.components.sigForm')"
    />
    <Separator
      img="/imgs/parallax5.jpeg"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PageTitle from '@/components/banner/parallax/PageTitle'
import Separator from '@/components/banner/parallax/Separator'
import SigForm from '@/components/generator/SigForm'

export default {
  name: 'Generator',
  components: {
    PageTitle,
    SigForm,
    Separator,
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Here is the 'PageTitle' component with a parallax container:

```
<template>
  <div class="parallax-container form-parallax-container">
    <h1 class="white-text center">{{ translations.title }}</h1>
    <div class="parallax"><img :src="img"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PageTitle',
  props: {
    translations: String,
    img: String
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

And here is the 'Separator' with a parallax container:

```
<template>
  <div class="parallax-container form-parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img :src="img"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Separator',
  props: {
    img: String
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

---UPDATE: Complete repo & sandboxed app---
Someone mentioned it would be eaiser if I provided a sandboxed app or whatever to debug it, so I just made the [github repo](https://github.com/robitwtms/email-sig-generator) public and also uploaded it to [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-visvesvaraya-7sri4). You'll notice that on codesandbox.io, the parallax images aren't even loading at all...on the homepage, on the form page, or upon refresh!

Comment: @depperm there. if you need any more code samples, just ask. I didn't want to overload the question with code, but I tried to include as much as possible without cluttering.

Comment: A workable demo that allows to debug the app would make it easier to solve. The question doesn't show how the router is configured but I assume that `<a>` reloads the page, hence the difference. Since Materialize wasn't built for SPA and Vue in particular, it's safe to assume that it initializes a parallax once and is unaware of further changes. You may notice that it explains how it's done in old-fashioned JS. You likely need to call `parallax()` every time a parallax needs to be initialized.

Comment: Unsolicited protip: Don't use line breaks for layout. Use global styles on your elements (`h1 {}`) or classes that apply margin or padding (`.margin-top {}`).

Comment: What does the browser console say? 404 for those image URLs? Then this likely is an issue with different base URLs used to complete the relative image URLs to absolute ones.

Comment: @CBroe the browser console doesn't have any warning or error's for the images. The only thing the browser console does say is a warning "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap"

Comment: The codesandbox appears to throw a lot of errors, starting with `$(...).dropdown is not a function`, and then several Vue warnings. Plus, if the images don’t properly show there to begin with, this is probably not that much helpful in reproducing the problem. So I stand by my guess - probably an issue with what the actual current client-side path is.

Comment: I think the answer is simple enough. When you refresh the browser, the image links get reloaded by the browser. When you transition using vue, it's up to vue and your code to reload the images and it's not being done for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not ***the*** answer, but I needed to post some code to illustrate.

I have to confess that I'm not fully au-fait with JS frameworks, but I do know materializecss very well. I've been trying to help another user with a React based problem where the sidenav stops working when the react router is used - until he refreshes the page, when it works fine again.

So here's my hunch:

[Parallax](https://materializecss.com/parallax.html) is a component that needs initialising like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
    var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parallax').parallax();
  });
```

If you leave that initialisation code out,  it won't work. And, taken from the docs for select fields [dynamically added components need reinitialising](https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization).

> You must initialize the select element as shown below. In addition,
>   you will need a separate call for any dynamically generated select
>   elements your page generates.

So my hunch is that when the page is re-rendered via a navigator, we get a new component added to the dom  - but this is after the initialisation has already run. So that component is not initialised.

Could be wrong, hope I'm not for your sake more than mine. As I said, I don't know Vue or React very well at all, and my suggestions to run the init at each render didn't work for the React issue - but there are so many moving parts it's hard to rule out.